# C# System.Type is namespace?

Tags: c#, reflection

```
System.Type type = Type.GetType("something");
```

`System.Type` has no member 'IsNamespace', so how do I tell if the type refers to a namespace?

The type `"something"` is not known at compile time.

Comment: You can use Type.IsNamespace(object); see : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383760.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @meganaut thats for asp.net ajax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has no member "IsNamespace" because namespaces **cannot be represented by `Type` objects**. The following line fails to compile:

```
typeof(System.Linq);
```

So assuming you have a `Type` object, you know its not a namespace. With a string like that, `GetType` should throw if it is just a namespace.

Answer (score 3):

`Type`s don't refer to namespaces - they refer to types. Types have a property which describe which namespace they are in.

You could enumerate all the types in an assembly/appdomain and collect/cache the unique namespaces.

```
HashSet<string> allNamespaces = new HashSet<string>(
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
        .Select(t => t.Namespace)
    );

bool isNamespace = allNamespaces.Contains("foo");
```

Comment: My intention was actually to take an arbitrary string as it would have been provided in code, and determine which '.' characters should be replaced with '+' so that Type.GetType() will work properly on it. So my logic was that parsing left to right, I could start swapping in '+' when I found the first non-namespace.

Comment: @bitwise what are you talking about?

Comment: I could just try swapping out each '.' with '+' until it works, but that would be a kludge performance-wise. Your solution would not be an improvement.

Comment: are you referring to nested types, not namespaces @bitwise?

Comment: Yes. I want to accept the full name of an arbitrarily nested class or struct. namespace.namespace.namespace.class.class, namespace.class.struct, class.struct.struct, etc, etc..

Comment: I feel like this beyond the scope of this question at this point though, so I should mark Brad as correct, since he was first, and ask a new question if needed. Thanks for the help.